# java -jar jarname does not unzip all resource files

Tags: java, maven, jar

I am creating an executable jar with maven and have added the following to my pom.xml under build section

```
<build>
.....
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/snmp</directory>
                             <includes>
                                 <include>**/*</include>
                             </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
.....
</build>
```

And I use the maven-shade-plugin to build jar with dependencies.

When I run the command after the build

```
java -jar jarName
```

It does not unzip all the files under src/main/snmp directory, for some reason it always unzips one file (the same file) every time. But if I do

```
jar -xf jarName
```

this unzips everything correctly.

Any other thing that I need to for using resources from a executable jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java -jar isn't supposed to extract anything, it's supposed to run whatever main method you've declared in your manifest.

What do you mean by "use resources from an executable jar"? If you mean access resources on the classpath from within the application, if you're doing it right, it should work fine-but there's no extraction.

Comment: When I say resources, it has to read a XML file that is packaged as part of the jar and to open that file, the program uses a relative path. Since java -jar does not unzip those files with in the current directory, the path provided in the program does not exist in the file system.

Comment: The file should be opened as a resource, not as a file system file.

Comment: It is a third party dependency that is doing it. I have to give it a directory location. You have any ideas to get around it?

Comment: If a component outside your control is expecting a file on the file system, just give it one. You could probably get the file as a resource and write it to the file system, if your goal is to distribute a single file.

Comment: Nah, there is more than one file. All I get to say is the directory where the files are residing and the third party library takes it and reads all the configuration. I guess I do not have any option but to unzip the jar before running it. Bad.

Comment: ... Or open the files as resourcesand write them to the file system.

Answer (score 1):

The command `java -jar jarName.jar` tries to execute the class, found in the jar, whose name is given by the `Main-Class` attribute in the manifest. In no way is it supposed to unzip the file. The command `jar xf jarname.jar`, on the other hand, is supposed to do exactly that.

If running the program with `java -jar` is unpacking something from the archive, then it's because the program found in the archive is designed to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't want to be extracting a JAR to run it. It's supposed to be self-contained. Put your resources in src/main/resources, and they'll be built into your jar at the root directory. Then use [Class.getResource()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) or [Class.getResourceAsStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to get it as a classpath resource.

**Edit:** Based on your comments, the first thing I think of is to go ahead and pack the files into your JAR, then at runtime, use [File.createTempFile()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to write them out to the default temporary directory, then give that directory to the third-party library to use. You can use [File.deleteOnExit()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#deleteOnExit%28%29) to clean up afterward.

Comment: Same reply as to Dave. There is a third party software which takes in a path from the file system and it proceeds to read all the configuration files in it and I have no control over it.